# CocoaLumberjack - File rolling when maximum file size is exceeded not working

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoalumberjack

I want to set up logging which creates a new file once the original file exceeds 1MB, up to a maximum of 5 files.

The issue is that currently I'm seeing the log file far exceeds 1MB and doesn't create a new file.

I'm using Objective C with CocoaLumberjack installed from CocoaPods. Testing with iphone simulator.

This is my code:

```
DDFileLogger *fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] init];

[fileLogger setRollingFrequency:-1];
[fileLogger setMaximumFileSize:1024*1024];
[[fileLogger logFileManager] setMaximumNumberOfLogFiles:5];

[DDLog addLogger:fileLogger];
```

I can't see where I've gone wrong but can't see anyone experiencing similar issues recently so I don't think there's a bug around it. Can anyone shed some light for me? Could it be to do with the iphone simulator? I unfortunately don't have a device at hand to test it on.